# Wordpress REST API Custom Endpoint with Users and Posts

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to create a new custom endpoint to list all users and their latest posts in one query.

I get an Error Message:
**array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null**

I don't see the problem, it should be an array or what is causing this issue?

My code:

```
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'myplugin/v1', '/author', array(
      'methods'  => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'my_custom_endpoint',

  ) );
} );

function my_custom_endpoint( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
  $users = get_users( array(

  ) );



$userQuery[] = $users;

    foreach ( $users as $key => $user ) {
             $posts_loop = get_posts( array(
                    'author' => (int)$user.data.ID
                ) );

                $add_featured_image = function( $post ) 
                    {   
                        $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post );
                          $post->thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_url( $image_id, 'large' );
                          return $post;
                        };


                $posts_processed = array_map( $add_featured_image, $posts_loop );       


        array_push($userQuery[$key], $posts_processed);

    }


  return $userQuery;
}
```

Comment: Problem is on this line array_push($userQuery[$key], $posts_processed);    have you tried with array_merge($array1,$array2);

Comment: @CyberAbhay yes, it throws the same error and the result is not what expected

Comment: For array_merge() your both array should have same dimensions.so first print both arrays to check using echo "<pre>"; print_r($your_array);   array_push() insert element at end of array and inserting element must have same dimension as original array